# My inset faces aren't working,. it only shows the dotted line in the center when i press I

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, faces

[image]

I'm doing the blender donut beginner tutorial.

I’ve checked the scale and everything, and have tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>. I saw that as an answer somewhere but still the inset isn’t working. it just keeps showing the dotted line in the center.

Comment: your pics cannot be seen. Your links are broken.

Comment: please don't use images taken by phone, rather use screenshots on your PC. Also, after pressing I and activating **insert face** you will get this interface with cross and dotted lines, which means your function that you are using is active and you have to either use numerical numbers or your Numpad or mouse to drag and click to use your function. I am not sure what you are doing and what you have selected.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score 2):

Inorder for your inset faces to work, there has to be an existing face.
right now, I guess, your mesh looks like this

[image]

If you inset the vertices which are active in the above image, you'll only get the dotted lines
Inorder for the inset faces to work (here), you'll have to fill it first by selecting those vertices and pressing "F" key
Once it's filled in, you can inset it by pressing "I" key, like it's shown below

[image]

I hope this answers your question